# Prevent default behavior when setting location.hash

Tags: javascript

When I do this,

```
location.hash = "test"
```

the url is updated and the page homes in on the element with that id.

Is there a way to stop the page from homing in to that element?

Comment: `location.hash` has nothing to do with jQuery, it is part of JavaScript. jQuery is JavaScript framework.

Comment: Why do you change `location.hash` if you don't want that effect?

Comment: @Tadeck I am working under that framework. It really doesn't matter to me if the solution is in pure JS or jQuery as long as it works.

Comment: @Zirak It is used in tab history. It is working fine. I just don't want to home in on the element for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Check out [the history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries)

Comment: @Zirak Not sure if that helps. I am not using History.js. But rest assured that I do use location.hash

Comment: The purpose of location.hash is to add something to URL. So it is contradictory while using it and also trying not to change URL

Comment: @Zirak I have no problems with changing the url. I am just concerned with the "homing" behavior. Are you saying that setting location.hash means that it will always home in to that element? No way around that behavior?

Comment: @arvinsim: See my answer for the "way around", although I discourage you from using it (better rething the code to not change `location.hash` if you do not want to move to the target part of the page). Also about jQuery vs. JavaScript statement: you will need to know JavaScript in detail when moving to more advanced projects, even if based on jQuery - you will need to know how it works in the back and how to use its concepts, more here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40845/how-necessary-is-it-to-learn-javascript-before-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

You cannot prevent this behaviour, but you can fool it by temporarily hiding the target, eg. like that (it has nothing to do with jQuery):

```
// obtain "target" DOM (not jQuery) element and do this:
var original_id = target.id; // save original ID
target.id = null; // set target's ID
location.hash = 'test'; // issue location.hash change
target.id = original_id; // set ID to original value
```

### Generalized solution

Or more general example:

```
// make target_hash set to a hash you want to not lead you to page section and:
var element = document.getElementById(target_hash); // find element by ID
var original_id = element.id; // save original ID
location.hash = target_hash; // previously defined by you (eg. 'test')
element.id = original_id; // reset ID
```

### Demo / proof

The live example can be as follows, in the event handler attached through jQuery (demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/DaZfH/):

```
some_link.on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = document.getElementById('target');
    var original_id = target.id;
    target.id = null; // unset ID
    location.hash = 'target';
    target.id = original_id;
});
```

### Disclaimer

But indeed others are right: moving you to the correct place in the document is the correct behaviour. If you are doing things like I mentioned, then your solution is pretty hakish and there is definitely a better way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to stop the page from homing in to that element

Yes. Although the hashchange event is not cancelable, you can reset its unwanted behavior like this.

```js
var popY,
    popX;

//When location.hash is changed, popstate is the first event to fire 
//Use this event to record current state

window.addEventListener('popstate', popstateHandler);
function popstateHandler() {
  popY = window.scrollY;
  popX = window.scrollX;
}

//Reset scroll position with recorded values when hashchange fires (after page is scrolled)

window.addEventListener('hashchange', hashchangeHandler);
function hashchangeHandler() {
  window.scrollTo(popX, popY);
}
```

That's the basis of it. You might want to do some proofing for IE, and implement your reasons for doing this: Animate scroll, active something etc..

Polyfill for scrollY, scrollX:

```js
if(!('scrollY' in window)) {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'scrollY', {
        get: function () {
            return window.pageYOffset
        }
    });
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'scrollX', {
        get: function () {
            return window.pageXOffset
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Using this approach technically works, however sometimes I could see a flicker caused by the jump back and forth (Browser: Chromium).