# preventDefault() does not work with window.location.hash on a click event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to make smooth scrolling in a single page application. In order to do this I am using window.location.hash statement in a click event handler like:

```
 $('a').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   let hash = this.hash;
   if (hash !== '') { 
   window.location.hash = hash
   // _scrollTo();
   }
 })
```

I am binding window's hashchange event to the above _scrollTo() function so that when user tries to get the url with hash, application should scroll there:

```
$(window)
.on("hashchange", _scrollTo)
.trigger("hashchange")
```

Scrolling function is like this:

```
  const _scrollTo = function () {
    var destination = $('body').find(window.location.hash);
    _scrollToDestination(destination, configMap.duration);
  }
```

I need to use this function because of fixed header on top of page, I dont want the scrolling to a section would be under header and user does not see that

```
  const _scrollToDestination = function (destination, duration) {
    let headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight(true);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: destination.offset().top - headerHeight
    }, duration);
  }
```

The problem is when I use the window.location.hash statement in click handler, event handler behaves as if default behaviour not prevented and I get weird results.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/yildirimmurat/pen/rNyNqjW)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are preventing the anchors mechanism but change the hash manually. That triggers another event in window actually.

Comment: Also, it might be that you cannot change the auto scroll behaviour. You can either use a simple hack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328647/prevent-default-behavior-when-setting-location-hash or change the target markup that the browser doesnt find the elements (use data-id instead of id/ name for instance)

Answer (score 0):

Simply preventing the default behaviour of window.location... worked for me

[How can I update window.location.hash without jumping the document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870057/how-can-i-update-window-location-hash-without-jumping-the-document)